# How to number line in file with exception (bash or sed)

Tags: bash, sed

I'd like to number all lines in my input file, except for this, that match my regexp. Ex:

Input file:

```
some text 12345
some another text qwerty
my special line
blah foo bar
```

Regexp: ^my

Output:

```
1 some text 12345
2 some another text qwerty
my special line
3 blah foo bar
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`awk` could do that pretty easily. Awk script:

```
!/^my/ {
  cnt++;
  printf "%d ", cnt
}
{
  print
}
```

Which means: for all lines that don't match the expression, increment the variable `cnt` (which starts out at zero) and print that number followed by a space. Then just print the whole line.

Demo:

```
 $ awk '!/^my/{cnt++; printf "%d ", cnt} {print}' input 
1 some text 12345
2 some another text qwerty
my special line
3 blah foo bar
```

A condensed version thanks to [Thor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331399/thor):

```
$ awk '!/^my/{$0=++cnt" "$0} 1' input
```

This works by modifying the whole line (`$0`) when the line doesn't match the expression (prepending the pre-incremented counter).
The `1` after the first `pattern{action}` pair is itself a `pattern{action}` pair with the action part omitted. `1` is always true, so the action is always executed, and the default action when none is specified is `{print}`. And `print` with no argument list is equivalent to `print $0`, i.e. print the whole line.

Comment: Or the shorter one: `!/^my/ { $0 = ++cnt " " $0 } 1`

Comment: Hadn't thought about modifying `$0`, that does work well in this case. And the lone `1` is an interesting shortcut, if a bit mysterious.